# Bash find hashtags from string

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm new to shell scripting and I'm trying to find all hashtags from a string using grep, this is what I have but it only works for alphanumeric characters

`echo '<span><span>#fooFOO0</span></span>' | grep -o '#[a-zA-Z0-9]'`

Comment: What do you mean by "find all"? Do you want the number of occurences ? Their position?

Comment: What do you mean by "only works for alphanumeric characters"? The regex wil work (or not) depending on more than just which characters, but also on criteria like order and position, ... For example: strictly speaking your test string *does* contain alphanumerics.

Perhaps it would help to post examples of what works and what doesn't. Making that distinction rigorously might enable you to see what's missing n the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hashtag finishes before `</span>`, you can do

```
echo '<span><span>#fooFOO0</span></span>' | grep -Po '#.*?(?=<)'
```

.*? means non-greedy search.

(?=<) is look-ahead.

Answer (score 0):

The following command print a line for each `hashtag` found:

```
❯ echo '<span><span>#fooFOO0</span>#foo #bar</span>' | grep --fixed-strings --only-matching '#'
#
#
#
```

#### Options

- `-F`, `--fixed-strings`

  > Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.
- `-o`, `--only-matching`

  > Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

**Warning:** `--count` or `-c` won't give the number of hashtags (`3`) but the number of lines containing one (only `1` here).